# How to use QPushButton to continue program

Tags: qt, qt5, qdialog, qpushbutton

I'm working on project to copy specific information from a server and a directory. It fully works as I want it to, so now I'm trying to create a GUI that describes what the program does, displays a progress bar, has 'Start' and 'Exit' buttons, and may or may not launch a window to display messages as the program processes the information. My question is, if I launch the QDialog window at the start of the program, before anything else runs, how do I cause the program to pause and wait until the 'Start' button is clicked? I can't seem to find anything that seems like what I'm looking for online, in the help file, or in a book I bought. I may just be overlooking it, though.

Comment: Almost all gui programs do what you want. The main window is displayed, but no further action is taken until the user interacts with the gui.

Comment: I am completely inexperienced in building a GUI. I'm using the designer in QT. I am only using a Dialog. Do I need to use a Main Window instead? Or is there something specific I need to put into the code of the 'Start' button before it will work? I currently have no code for the button because I don't know where to even start with it.

Comment: I recommend that you copy an example app available on internet. Normally, you would use a `QMainWindow`. You need to create a slot which starts the program that the gui is meant to drive. The slot shall be connected to the `QPushButton::clicked()` signal.